# Issue with Input Type = number in Internet explorer and edge for angularjs code

Tags: angularjs, npm, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, polyfills

Can anyone point me to a sample application where NPM number polyfills has been used with angularjs code. I have a fairly simple application which has a control input type=number with increment decrement functionality, which is working fine in chrome and firefox. However the same is not supported in ie or edge.I know its an existing issue with IE and have seen polyfills could solve this but not sure how.Can any one please help me on this.